# Requesting credentials from users

Tags: python, comparative-review

I need to handle configuration errors and ask the user for the right credentials if something is wrong. I cannot decide between three implementations. Which style is better in Python and why?

A:

```
while not backend.check_config():
    click.echo('Invalid Configuration parameters!')
    for param_name, question in backend.config.check_config_requires:
        value = prompt(question, default=getattr(backend.config, param_name))
        setattr(backend.config, param_name, value)
```

B:

```
while True:
    try:
        backend.check_config()
        break
    except ConfigurationError:
        click.echo('Invalid Configuration parameters!')
        for param_name, question in backend.config.check_config_requires:
            value =prompt(question, default=getattr(backend.config, param_name))
            setattr(backend.config, param_name, value)
```

C:

```
while True:
    try:
        backend.check_config()
    except ConfigurationError:
        click.echo('Invalid Configuration parameters!')
        for param_name, question in backend.config.check_config_requires:
            value =prompt(question, default=getattr(backend.config, param_name))
            setattr(backend.config, param_name, value)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `backend.check_config()` is different between your implementations.  In one case, it seems to return a boolean, but the other two make it look like it might raise an exception.  My answer is based on that assumption.

---

The name of the function is `check_config`.  If it were, `parse_config`, for example, I would say that it should throw an error because it is expected to do something, but can't because of a problem.  Since it is merely checking, I think a boolean fits better, so my preference goes to **A**.

---

Between B and C, it looks like the only difference is whether `break` is in the `try` block or the `else` block.  I am happy to see that you are aware of the `else` block, but my opinion is that it isn't necessary.  The `else` block is useful for the cases when you are trying to exclude a certain piece of code from the `try` block.  That makes sense for when the `try` is in another `try`, or for when you don't expect an error and want to *know* the error happened.  In this case, it is impossible for `break` to throw an error, so I believe the `else` block is an unnecessary complication.

I did notice that you took out the space between `=` and `prompt(...)` in B and C.  PEP 8, the Python style guide, recommends a space on each side of `=` in assignments. (It recommends no spaces in a function call such as `dict(x=4, y=6)`)  That could be just a typo, but this *is* a review.

---

Based on how you use it, I would think that `backend.config` would be better as a dictionary.  That way, you could do `backend.config[param_name]` instead of the more complicated `getattr(backend.config, param_name)` (or `settattr(...)`).  If `config` is created externally, you might consider using `vars(config)` to create a dictionary of its attributes.  Without further information, I couldn't guarantee that it would be easier, but that's how it looks.

Comment: Awesome review, thank you! Yes, check_config() is different. I didn't even thought of making config dict-like. I introduced a method `config.set_param()` and `config.get_param()` but it's not really better than setattr and getattr. Space typo :)